# what component can set style in react native ?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

in my project , i use react-swipeable-views-native set swiper and next is listView , swiper component has default style

```
 flex:1
```

when i set listView style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    swiperContainer:{
        height: 200,
        flex: 2 
    },
    listContainer:{
        flex:5
    }
})
```

,
it not work , but set swiper component `flex:0` , it can work , i guess in react native `View`,`Text` etc can set style , but some one can't set style like `listView` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set styles using property `contentContainerStyle` for **ListView** (inherited from **ScrollView**). In practice: `<ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.listContainer} ...>`

If you're on RN 0.43+, I prefer using [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) over **ListView**.